# PHP Call a function from another function in same class

Tags: php

I am unable figure out how to make this work any help will be appreciated

```
<?php
 class some{

function display()
{
    $w ="its working";
    $this->show($w);

}
function show($s)
{
    echo $s;
}

}

?>
```

Comment: `$W` and `$w` are not the same variable

Comment: Then please define what it is you mean by *"make this work."* As it stands, it's perfectly valid code. Unless you forgot to make an instance of `some` and call its `display()` method?

Comment: its not working hanky....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were rightly advised to create an instance of your class then call the method on it but you **[said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349202/php-call-a-function-from-another-function-in-same-class/36349365#comment60319388_36349264)**

> see thats what i don't want .....i want some way to make it work without adding those two lines...by doing something else...just not that...and i can't figure out what i can do.

That something else is Simple! Make your method **[static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)**

> Declaring class properties or methods as static makes them accessible without needing an instantiation of the class.

```
public static function display()
{
    $w ="its working";
    self::show($w);
}
```

Then you can just do

```
some::display();
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/545976)**

Answer (score 1):

well it is working if you add the last two lines:

```
<?php
 class some{

function display()
{
    $w ="its working";
    $this->show($w);

}
function show($s)
{
    echo $s;
}

}

$x = new some;
$x->display();

?>
```

[see here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/84dae53238ec886fc1b2186367d621802e970118) and click on "execute code"

Comment: see thats what i don't want .....i want some way to make it work without adding those two lines...by doing something else...just not that...and i can't figure out what i can do

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are not called to display() function. Call to that function and try again.